# Best place to store Credit Card info during 3D secure check

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, 3d-secure

Am in the process of implementing 3D secure on our website. I've got the authentication process running smoothly however the 3D secure check requires a redirect away from the site while it goes to the card holder's bank's page and back again. This means the credit card info entered at the start of the process has since been lost in the ether. I'm wandering what the best to temporarily store this data might be. For PCI compliance reasons, we can't store it in our database, our website sits in a load balanced server farm and we can't guarantee the user will be returned to the same server so we can't put it in Session state. To me that only seems to leave storing the data in a cookie, which would require encryption.

Has anyone got any other ideas?

Comment: depends on your gateway provider and how they need it. check their documentation. some  provide it in the headers/body as part of the POST process.

Comment: I think you need to see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577677/asp-net-handling-session-data-in-a-load-balanced-environment You can use Session state even when in a load balanced environment.

Comment: Response from the gateway provider is just XML with basic information as to whether it's authorised or not. No card data is passed.

Comment: Have had reliability issues with sticky sessions in the past. It's possible it's something I'm not configuring correctly but with such a critical step in the payment process I don't want risk causing an error if I can avoid it.

Comment: You don't really need it at the 3Dsecure screen, unless if you want to redirect the customer to the card details screen in case the 3DSecure authentication fails. In this case the Session object is a good place to store it (including other details like expiry date, card name, secure code etc)