# ASP.NET Core web application session mix-up issue

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In our ASP.NET Core application, I'm getting a session mix-up issue.

I used this code for session assign and get:

Set to `Session`:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("MandateSession_Data", Session_Data);
```

Get from `Session`:

```
Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Session_Data"));
```

Added some config changes still getting few user this issue.

Comment: used below config level setting.

 <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false"></caching>

Comment: Could you please elaborate your issue in detail?

Comment: Yes, In our app developed in .net core 2.2 and used session for user data store. In some time repo class session mixing (user A data showing in user B screen). This issue happing in prod env.

Comment: Is it a single production server or do you have load balancing servers?

Comment: site running on load balancing servers and app hosted on 2 server.

Comment: Found something on "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577677/asp-net-handling-session-data-in-a-load-balanced-environment". Have a look and see if it is helpful.